# How did Cruella de Vil and Ursula not age a bit?

Tags: character, once-upon-a-time

In *Once Upon a Time*, Cruella de Vil and Ursula were not in Storybrooke when they got stuck in Land without magic. So why does their age not change in 28 years?

In Land without Magic, people do get old as happened with Neil, August, Lily and Emma, but why didn't Cruella de Vil and Ursula change a bit?

Comment: Aren't they witches?

Comment: @WBT Ursula was a semi-mermaid/witch and Cruella de Vil is human ( with power to control animal) .  Cora was witch too but she did turn old.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cruella_de_Vil#Once_Upon_a_Time) describes Cruella "as a witch who possesses the power to control animals" who had a childhood and grew up (showing aging), and also drank a potion to make her grow much older in a very short time (hence the hair color).  Hope that helps.

Comment: @WBT it have nothing to do with her age getting stopped. Does it, if yes then when does it even mentioned?

Comment: We don't actually know that they were in the "real world" outside Storybrooke for the entire time. It's possible they were in Storybrooke until the curse was broken and then left.

Answer (score 1):

When Cruella, Ursula and Lily got sucked up by the portal, they used the egg's magical powers to keep them young. From [wiki](http://onceuponatimeabc.wikia.com/wiki/Cruella_De_Vil)

Comment: Is it mentioned in some episode?

Comment: I think it's in episodes 17 or 18 of season 4. Will rewatch it to check.

Comment: Did you got time to confirm it?

Answer (score -3):

Basiclly there were scenes in season 4.5 portraying diffrent parts on Cruella and Ursula when they were younger. Also Ursula was a sea witch( There probably a spell)  and Cruella can control animals (Humans are animal so maybe she  can control herself or do something like that to make herself younger)

Or the most realistic approach,

Makeup and Plastic Surgery (Since both of them were in the human world at some time during the season)

Comment: Do you have any evidence **from the show** to support your answer? It seems like two theories as is.

Comment: There were certain scenes during the season that showed the younger versions of Ursula (On the rocks, singing) and Cruella (when she was kept in the room by her mother). Some of what i said where theories/conspiracies or ideas that can be possible in some way. Though it can be more fact-like due some of what i said in "()".